# How to verify that WSL 2 is used?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

It seems the api has changed and the command that one can find online are mostly outdated. How can I change which version of Windows Subsystem for Linux is used?

Formerly:

```
wsl -l -v
```

## Update

After, upgrading windows to 2004 I was able to use the above command in the Power Shell.

```
wsl -l -v
>   NAME            STATE           VERSION
> * Ubuntu-18.04    Running         2
```

Is that sufficient as a confirmation? The wsl shell's of wsl 1 and 2 seem to look identical.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Comment: Apparently, not all updates are installed yet.

Comment: To update to WSL 2, you must meet the follow criteria: [Running Windows 10, updated to version 2004, Build 19041 or higher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#update-to-wsl-2).

Comment: Damn, I already ran the updates, but of course, not all updates are installed at once.

Comment: In your update. Yes it is enough confirmation your Ubuntu is running WSL 2. You can also use uname and see kernel version 4.19. Another confirmation is that installing a package is a lot faster

Comment: @Sören - Your original question was answered.  You shouldn’t edit your question in an effort to get an answer to a unrelated question.  Despite the fact you added an unrelated question the current answer still answers it

Comment: It is still the same question. I only noticed my former assumption that I ran the correct build of W10 was invalid and then fixed. The question of how to confirm that WSL2 runs remains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. At a Windows command prompt, run `ver`  Is the next-to-last numeric group version **18917** or higher? If so, go on to step 2. If not, you have version 1. This illustrates the result when the OS is Build 16299:

[image]

2. Open Windows *PowerShell* (not the Command Prompt) and enter the command `wsl -l -v`

If version 2 is installed properly, you will see the version number.

If you don't see a version number, or if you see an error message, you have version 1.

[image]

Comment: And when is start wsl with `wsl` who do I know the correct one is started? They look the same?

Comment: If you don't have a Windows 10 Insider Build, you have not got WSL2

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's my Step  1.

Comment: Soren, the command line with switches as shown in step 2, when started _from inside PowerShell_ just shows the version of WSL.

Comment: The two shells look pretty much alike, so I wasn't sure if that is enough.

Comment: If they were the same thing, why would M$ develop the new version. Big difference under the hood.