# Check WSL version (1 or 2) *inside the Linux installation*

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

You can check which version is each installed distribution with the command,

```
wsl -l -v
```

as [this superuser question states](https://superuser.com/questions/1551146/how-to-verify-that-wsl-2-is-used).

But is it possible to know the WSL version (1 or 2) from inside the Linux installation?

Is there any reliable mechanism to check the version?

### What I found?

#### Environment and "interop"

The only difference in environment variables, is that WSL 2 has one named `WSL_INTEROP` that version 1 has not.

That variable points to a path special file.

#### Kernel version

[This reddit post reply points](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/hwkjck/is_there_a_reliable_and_portable_way_to_check_if/fz0jjqx?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to use the following command,

```
uname -r | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

WSL 1 output:

```
4.4.0-19041-microsoft
```

WSL 2 output:

```
5.4.72-microsoft-standard-wsl2
```

Could this be an option **except** the replies given,

> Probably better not to go with a kernel check as you can build and install your own kernel, and some people would strip that out.

Although [this askubuntu accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177730/305412) states

> If the kernel version => 4.19, it's WSL Version 2.

Any other options/ideas?

**Addendum**: [github/WSL repo has the issue #4555](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4555).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running WSL within WSL will work:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -v
```

The output isn't ascii so you could convert then match on the env var WSL_DISTRO_NAME:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f unicode | dos2unix |grep $WSL_DISTRO_NAME | awk '{print $NF}'
```

'

Your installation may need to do some other character conversion.

**Edit**

If running multiple distributions of similar names, using egrep will be more reliable:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f unicode | dos2unix |egrep "\b$WSL_DISTRO_NAME\s+Running" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: The could not say anything related to WSL version 1 or 2, so does not help.

Comment: I misread question

Comment: I've replaced the answer, but am not able to test fully as I've only one distro installed.

Comment: Good catch! [Inception](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/) style :P

Comment: This doesn't work properly if there is more than one distro that contains the same name. E.g., I have a distro called Ubuntu and another called Ubuntu-20.04 both on WSL2 and I get two 2s returned (one for each distro).

Comment: Changing the `grep` to `egrep "\b$WSL_DISTRO_NAME\s+Running"` should help fix that so that similarly named distributions are filtered

Answer (score 5):

I think I prefer @DuncG's answer.  I think the only way it could fail would be if `Interop` was disabled in `/etc/wsl.conf`.  As long as you are confident that interop is always turned on, that seems like the way to go.

But I'll add that there are quite a few differences between WSL1 and WSL2 that could be used as classification.

---

Assuming you are using automounting of the Windows' drives:

- `mount | grep "/mnt/c" | grep -q drvfs` returns success for WSL1 and fails on WSL2
- `mount | grep "/mnt/c" | grep -q 9p` returns success for WSL2 and fails on WSL1

---

Also, `lscpu`, but this command is missing from Alpine by default (available on Ubuntu and Kali, for sure, and I would assume on Debian):

- `lscpu | grep -q "Hypervisor vendor:.*Microsoft"` will succeed on WSL2 but fail on WSL1, since only WSL2 runs under Hyper-V.

---

I'm not 100% sure on this one, but in every case I tested (Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL1 and WSL2, Kali on WSL1 and WSL2, and Alpine on WSL1 and WSL2):

- `/proc/cmdline` on WSL1 is `BOOT_IMAGE=/kernel init=/init`
- `/proc/cmdline` on WSL2 is `initrd=\initrd.img panic=-1 pty.legacy_count=0 nr_cpus=16` *(update note:  recent WSL2 releases with Systemd support change this slightly.  And, of course, using `.wslconfig` to set kernel cmdline arguments will change this as well.
  However, the examples below still work in either of those cases.)*

So:

- `grep -q "^BOOT_IMAGE" /proc/cmdline` returns success on WSL1 but error on WSL2
- `grep -q "^initrd" /proc/cmdline` returns success on WSL2 but error on WSL1

I'm sure there are others, but these are some possibilities if you ever need them.

Comment: Wow! Nice investigation!

Comment: Really nice work. Probably we can create a shell using this information. However, I think there are many border cases to consider. For instance, you may change the `/mnt/c` mount point in the `wsl.conf`. Probably the hypervisor signature may appear if you run a heavy-weight virtual machine too. I think a complete solution will require a combination of checks.